# Как реализовать обратный отчет двумя DateTime?

Tags: flutter, dart

я получаю с бэка "sms_timeout":"2021-04-15 18:33:34", то есть кнопка должен загореться в это время или если реальное время превышает это время("sms_timeout")

таймер каждую секунду должен отнимать от полученного времени реальное время и показывать сколько времени (в формате `mm:ss`) осталось до загорания кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Переведите строку в нужный формат с помощью `DateTime.parse()`.

Запустите таймер и каждую секунду рассчитывайте разницу между этим временем и текущим.

Разницу выводите в нужном формате.

При надобности подумайте над ситуацией, когда пользователь перевёл время вручную.